# PHPExcel - Divide records for printing

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to create something like this:

[image]

I have 100 records in my MySQL database. I want them to be divided by 25 records per table so that when I print, I can have 25 records per bond paper.

It's like it needs looping or something.

Please help, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at the limit and offset keywords for mysql.

It could look something like this:

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYMENTS LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;

For the next 25 records your offset should be set as 25.

This can be done by looping.

I know that this is not an answer but maybe it can guide you in the right direction or at least another direction or maybe just a direction.